# How to play offline?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-source

I have completed all Downloads for Counter Strike: Source, now I want to play offline.
So, Please give a detailed procedure for playing offline.

Answer (score 2):

Open the dropdown menu in Steam.
Switch to offline mode.

[image: Go offline]
[image: Go Offline]

Open CS:S and play.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do to play offline is create a server and put a password on it (this field is under the "Game" tab after you click "Create Server").